# Best way to update a lot of data with difference value?

Tags: laravel

I have a lot of data and each record have difference value. I try to loop insert/update data but it take time. Is it have better way to improve my code?

I don't want to delete all data before update.

```
 $data = [ 
        [ 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'A' ],
        [ 'id' => 2, 'name' => 'B' ],
        [ 'id' => 3, 'name' => 'C' ],
        [ 'id' => 4, 'name' => 'D' ],
          .
          .
          .
        [ 'id' => 10000, 'name' => 'ZYX' ],
    ]

 foreach ($data as $item) {
        DB::table('my_table')->updateOrInsert(['id' => $item->id], $item);
 }
```

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `upsert` in Laravel 8.x or use this package: https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-upsert to use INSERT ON DUPLICATE

```php
$data = [ 
  [ 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'A' ],
  [ 'id' => 2, 'name' => 'B' ],
  [ 'id' => 3, 'name' => 'C' ],
  [ 'id' => 4, 'name' => 'D' ],
          .
          .
          .
  [ 'id' => 10000, 'name' => 'ZYX' ],
];

DB::table('my_table')->upsert($data, 'id');
```

Answer (score 0):

use laravel [upsert](https://www.amitmerchant.com/insert-or-update-multiple-records-using-upsert-in-laravel8/) method here

for example you want to update if exists or insert record if not exists

```
$data = [
    [
        'id' => 1
        'name' => 'J.K. Rowling', 
        'author' => 'Harry Potter', 
        'quantity' => 15
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2  
        'name' => 'Cal Newport', 
        'author' => 'Deep Work', 
        'quantity' => 20
    ]
];

DB::table('books')->upsert($data, ['id'], ['quantity']);
```

1.The first argument consists of the values to insert or update.

2.The second argument lists the column(s) that uniquely identify records (id in our case) within the associated table.

3.The third and final argument is an array of columns that should be updated if a matching record already exists in the database. We want the quantity to be updated in our case.

for more detail read official docs [upsert](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts)